# Firebase doesn't sync events with BigQuery even after four days

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

**Four days ago** I linked my **Firebase** project to **BigQuery**. Several bunches of events were generated since then (around 20).
However, **BigQuery** still does not contain any related datasets.

The events are 100% linked which is indicated by the notification (and the link) **VIEW your raw events in BigQuery** below the list of events.

[image]

However, after following the link, no related datasets can be seen in BigQuery

[image]

It is frustrating because Google documentation says that events will flow from Firebase to BigQuery and this will automatically create the BigQuery dataset and its daily tables.

How to get the events into BigQuery? Do I miss something?

Comment: The first screenshot shows the configuration for sending events from Firebase Analytics to BigQuery, which has nothing to do with whether events are sent from Crashlytics to BigQuery. If you've enabled sending of Crashlytics events to BigQuery and those are not showing up, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: But I am not interested in Crashanalytics, but in Events themselves. It is Events that are absent from BigQuery that what upsets me.

Comment: Ah, got it. I was confused by the second screenshot since you have crashlytics selected there. From what I now understand your question is about the missing of an analytics table on the left. As far as I know Analytics export is only available when your Firebase project is on a paid plan. Is that the case?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, yes, it is the case.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure why they wouldn't show up. You might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Comment: hi @DmytroSly how do you solved it ? i have a same issue with you, i will be waiting your response

Answer (score 1):

If you add a new app into already enabled bigquery project. It doesn't automatically start exporting data into bigquery

STEPS to reproduce

- Add an app into firbease
- Enable Bigquery
- events start showing into bigquery
- Add another app into same project as above
- Bigquery is already linked on the project. However what i observed is that newly added app doesn't get automatically added to "Apps exporting".
- Hence events are not listed on bigquery, even after waiting for few days

So whenever you add a new app.

Goto **Project Settings**

Goto BigQuery->Manage

Goto "Analytics"

[image]

Make sure **app export** is enabled for newly added app