# Firebase data is not exporting to BigQuery after release of new versions of my app

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have exported analytics data from big query.It was working till the new version is released. After release of new version i could not see any data in BigQuery, but I can see the data in Firebase report/console, but not in BigQuery.
Could you please help me to understand, why I don't see the data for new versions? What are the conditions of data export?
[Attached Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwrQN.png)

Comment: Looks similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/55515677/1031958 hope @frank can help you with this

Comment: @TamirKlein Thanks for your reply. But it does not seems to be similar because I actually got the BigQuery data for few days.After that it stopped exporting.

Answer (score 1):

Loading data from Cloud Firestore exports has its [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#).  BigQuery and Cloud Storage also require some [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#required_permissions).

You need to make sure [options'](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#cloud_firestore_) specifications is needed to change how BigQuery parses Cloud Firestore export data, and data type [conversion](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#data_type_conversion).

After reviewing other similar issues that occurred with the release of new versions of apps, make sure that the app still has [Analytics-linked to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics) in the integrations section in the Firebase console.